# iOS WKWebView pauses JavaScript thread in several cases. How to keep JS running?

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

If I hide the WKWebView, or turn off screen, or sometimes if I leave WKWebView open for a while, I noticed that the JavaScript thread gets paused.

Is there any way to keep the JS thread executing codes in those cases?